# Как подключиться к Web Services без референции?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, visual-studio, service

Как подключиться к Web Services без референции? Есть какие идеи?

Comment: @renkorpeso, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Ещё не мешало бы как-то обозначить, что такое "референция" и какая технология веб-сервисов (WCF, Restful, ...) имеется в виду.

Answer (score 2):

Предоставить клиенту длл с сервисными контрактами, а дальше через `ChannelFactory`, например. Или вопроизвести все контракты у себя. Или вообще руками байтики слать.